# Can I use an image with text to prevent search engines from showing that text in the search results snippet?

Tags: seo, images, text

I have content on my website that is being picked up by search engines and shown the in the search results snippet.   I'd rather noth have that text shown there.

Is putting this text in an image a suitable option to stop search engines from from seeing it and showing it?

Comment: Do you not want that text indexed at all? I would assume not if the information is sensitive enough that you don't want it shown in the SERPs. Then you have to ask, should this _page_ be indexable in the first place?